# Exception when URI does not exist

Tags: android

When I try open "sound" from the settings app, it crashes with this exception:

```
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-773
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown URL: content://media/internal/audio/media/30/30
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1433)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at com.android.settings.SoundSettings.updateRingtoneName(SoundSettings.java:331)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at com.android.settings.SoundSettings.access$300(SoundSettings.java:52)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at com.android.settings.SoundSettings$3.run(SoundSettings.java:252)
11-11 19:47:40.080: E/AndroidRuntime(6305):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

It seems as though this URI does not exist:

> content://media/internal/audio/media/30/30

I've run a

> Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/30/30").getPath()

and I get back

> /internal/audio/media/30/30

But /internal does not exist on the filesystem of my device.

**My Question is, how do I create this file that the URI references so the app will not crash because it is missing?**

Thanks

Comment: Could you just put a try/catch around it, and in the catch part tell the user that the file does not exist

Comment: I have no control over this code that runs, it's the android OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, but it isn't ideal (you have to wipe your phone): the fix to this problem was to do a "Factory data reset" without the "Automatic restore" option enabled.

You'll get a clean phone and this error will disappear.

Another fix that didn't work for me but seemed to work for others is in "Manage apps" to clear the cache and data of any app with the word "settings" in it, i.e. "Settings", "System settings"

I'm still not sure what causes this issue, it manifests itself after a brief period of using the phone: could it be caused by installing a specific app?